# Java square root approximation program with while loop

Tags: java, math, while-loop

I'm trying to make program that approximates the square root of a number via squeeze theorem. If a number is above one (easy example is 100), it sets the interval to [1, 100], takes the midpoint and if the square of that number is greater than 100, it updates high and prints the new interval. If it's lower, it updates low until the space between them is within EPSILON. My problem is that I can't seem to get it to go inside the else statement to update low. All of the output before that is correct. It prints the first five lines correctly then terminates without updating low.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter a number to find its square root -> ");

    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
    double number = cin.nextDouble(); 
    double low = 0;
    double high = 0; 
    double midPoint;
    double midPointSqr;
    final double EPSILON = .000001;

        if (number < 0)
            System.out.printf("The square root of %f is NaN%n", number);
        else if (number < 1) {
            low = 0; high = 1;
        }
        else {
            low = 1; 
            high = number;
            midPoint = (low+high)/2; 
            midPointSqr = (midPoint*midPoint);
            System.out.printf("[%.6f, %.6f]%n", low, high);
            high = midPoint;
            System.out.printf("[%.6f, %.6f]%n", low, high);
            while ((Math.abs(midPoint*midPoint)-number) >= EPSILON) {
                midPoint = (low+high)/2;
                if (midPointSqr > number) {
                    high = midPoint;
                    System.out.printf("[%.6f, %.6f]%n", low, high);
                    midPoint = (low+high)/2;
                    midPointSqr = midPoint*midPoint; 
                }
                else if (midPointSqr == number)
                    System.out.println("null");
                else {
                    low = midPoint;
                    System.out.printf("[%.6f, %.6f]%n", low, high);
                    midPoint = (low+high)/2;
                    midPointSqr = midPoint*midPoint;
                }
            }

        }
/*Output should look like this
1 Enter a number to find its square root -> 100
2 [1.000000 , 100.000000]
3 [1.000000 , 50.500000]
4 [1.000000 , 25.750000]
5 [1.000000 , 13.375000]
6 [7.187500 , 13.375000]
7 [7.187500 , 10.281250]
8 [8.734375 , 10.281250]
9 [9.507813 , 10.281250]
10 [9.894531 , 10.281250]
11 [9.894531 , 10.087891]
12 [9.991211 , 10.087891]
13 [9.991211 , 10.039551]
14 [9.991211 , 10.015381]
15 [9.991211 , 10.003296]
16 [9.997253 , 10.003296]
17 [9.997253 , 10.000275]
18 [9.998764 , 10.000275]
19 [9.999519 , 10.000275]
20 [9.999897 , 10.000275]
21 [9.999897 , 10.000086]
22 [9.999991 , 10.000086]
23 [9.999991 , 10.000039]
24 [9.999991 , 10.000015]
25 [9.999991 , 10.000003]
26 [9.999997 , 10.000003]
27 [9.999997 , 10.000000]
28 [9.999999 , 10.000000]
29 [10.000000 , 10.000000]
*/
```

Comment: Also, as you can see, I haven't yet filled out the contingency of a number between 0 and 1 which I'd believe would be the same save for different starting interval. Additionally, the else if in the while loop is merely a placeholder-will get deleted/updated later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my cleaned up version of your code:

```
public static double approximateSqrt(double number) {
    double low = 0;
    double high = 0;
    double midPoint;
    double midPointSqr;
    final double EPSILON = .000001;

    if (number < 0) {
        System.out.printf("The square root of %f is NaN%n", number);
        return Double.NaN;
    } else if (number < 1) {
        low = 0;
        high = 1;
    } else {
        low = 1;
        high = number;
    }
    midPoint = (low + high) / 2;
    midPointSqr = (midPoint * midPoint);

    while (Math.abs(midPointSqr - number) >= EPSILON) {
        System.out.printf("[%.6f, %.6f]%n", low, high);

        if (midPointSqr > number) {
            high = midPoint;
        } else {
            low = midPoint;
        }

        midPoint = (low + high) / 2;
        midPointSqr = (midPoint * midPoint);
    }
    System.out.printf("Final. midpoint=%.6f num=%.6f%n", midPoint, number);
    return midPoint;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number to find its square root -> ");
    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
    double number = cin.nextDouble();
    approximateSqrt(number);
}
```

Comment: Not supposed to use comments to thank, but I merely asked to know what was wrong with my loop/condition, but instead-you fixed the entire code and made it far cleaner as well. Thank you very much.